# Changing colors of JButtons of LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I am working on an Java application, and I'm setting the LookAndFeel. Everything of the LAF I like except the default background color of the JButtons. What's the best way to set that (and other properties) after I set the look and feel? I don't want to have to create my own look and feel that extends it... would love to just be able to change it after the line I set the LAF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself shortly afterwards.

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.background",new Color(0xFFFFFF));
```